# Laravel 5.1 project deployement permissions issues

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to deploy my laravel project. I have installed apache, mysql, php, composer and laravel and pulled my project into /home/spark and ran composer install. Now when I surf to my ip I only see the apache test page.

When I take a peek in my log files I see these 2 errors:

```
[Sun Nov 22 17:37:54.598627 2015] [core:error] [pid 16141] (13)Permission denied: [client 78.20.130.157:50142] AH00035: access to /index.html denied (filesystem path '/home/spark/public/index.html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Sun Nov 22 17:37:54.598708 2015] [core:error] [pid 16141] (13)Permission denied: [client 78.20.130.157:50142] AH00035: access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/home/spark/public/index.php') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I have no idea how to fix the permessions. Anyone can help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Here's my spark.conf file for my virtualhost maybe it's not good either:

```
<Directory "/home/spark/public">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myurl
    DocumentRoot "/home/spark/public"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-error"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-customlog" Common
</VirtualHost>
```

the permissions on my files in /home/spark/public

```
drwxr-x---  5 root  root   4096 Nov 22 16:33 .
drwxr-x--- 13 spark apache 4096 Nov 22 16:35 ..
drwxr-x---  2 root  root   4096 Nov 22 16:33 css
-rwxr-x---  1 root  root      0 Nov 22 16:33 favicon.ico
-rwxr-x---  1 root  root    412 Nov 22 16:33 .htaccess
drwxr-x---  2 root  root   4096 Nov 22 16:33 images
-rwxr-x---  1 root  root   1786 Nov 22 16:33 index.php
-rwxr-x---  1 root  root     24 Nov 22 16:33 robots.txt
drwxr-x---  3 root  root   4096 Nov 22 16:33 uploads
```

Comment: can you please show us the permissions of the folders and files of your Laravel app, if you're on Linux, just go to your directory using `cd /home/spark/public` and then use this command to show files and directories permissions `ls -al`

Comment: I edited OP with permissions as you asked

Comment: Now try to make apache the owner of all your application folders like so :
`sudo chown -R apache:apache .` , your current folder should be the application folder before running this command

Comment: application folder I assume this is /home/spark in my case?

Comment: Yes, cd to that directory and change the owner of the application folders and files recursively with the command `chown`

Comment: ok great I've done this and I finally see something else than the apache testpage, I see laravel. It's an error but at least it's laravel :) the error is PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver maybe you know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please paste the text of the error, I'll make an answer to your question so if in the future someone has the same problem can solve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95870/discussion-between-moussa-chaabar-and-teeyo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make apache the owner of all your application folders and files like so :

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache .
```

your current folder should be the application folder before running this command